# Twitter digits в desktop приложении

Tags: java, javafx, twitter

Я хочу использовать авторизацию через twitter digits в моем javaFX приложении.

Это возможно ?

На их сайте я нашел поддержку ios,android, web сайты, но о desktop ни слова. 
И то с сайтами у них тоже как то не понятно, я гуглил но все как то мутно.
Как можно решить мою проблему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Врятли. Если я правильно понял то тут идет идентификация через СМС.

> Twitter собирается заменить логин номером сотового, а пароль — одноразовым SMS-кодом #passwords

[Сама новость.](https://www.kaspersky.ru/blog/twitter-digits-new-authentication/5785/)